# Why are the widths of my bar graph abnormal?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a candlestick chart with a graph of the trading volume of the stock under it. I don't know why the some of the bars are randomly sticking together. What could the problem behind this? The code:

```
bar_width = 0.8
stick_width = 0.1
fig_size = (10, 1)
line_width = 2

width = [0.8]*104

def plotstock(df: pd.DataFrame, output_plot_dir: str):
    df = df.reset_index()
    up = df[df.close >= df.open]
    down = df[df.close < df.open]

    plt.figure(figsize=fig_size, dpi=80)
    plt.style.use('default')
    figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, height_ratios=[3,1])
    axis[0].margins(x=0.0, y=0.1)
    axis[1].margins(x=0.0, y=0.1)

    # Draw the price history
    axis[0].bar(up.index, up.close-up.open, bar_width, bottom=up.open, color=bull_color) 
    axis[0].bar(up.index, up.high-up.close, stick_width, bottom=up.close, color=bull_color) 
    axis[0].bar(up.index, up.low-up.open, stick_width, bottom=up.open, color=bull_color)

    axis[0].bar(down.index, down.close-down.open, bar_width, bottom=down.open, color=bear_color) 
    axis[0].bar(down.index, down.high-down.open, stick_width, bottom=down.open, color=bear_color) 
    axis[0].bar(down.index, down.low-down.close, stick_width, bottom=down.close, color=bear_color)

    axis[0].plot(df.wma30, color=wma30_color, linewidth=line_width)
    axis[0].axhline(df.iloc[-1].fyh, color=fyh_color, linewidth=line_width)

    axis[0].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axis[0].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # Draw the volume
    # print(df["volume"].values)
    axis[1].bar(df.index, df["volume"].values, width=width)
    
    axis[1].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axis[1].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

[image]

We tried to change the fig_size,change the width, use .values instead of the original df.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be with the width values you're passing for the bars in the volume plot. You're giving a list of the same width value for all bars, but that causes an overlap if the index values are too close together. Your alternative is to compute it dynamically.

Here is how I would have done that (note the picture is crappy since I do not have your data, so simply random values)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', periods=104),
    'open': np.random.rand(104) * 100,
    'high': np.random.rand(104) * 100,
    'low': np.random.rand(104) * 100,
    'close': np.random.rand(104) * 100,
    'volume': np.random.randint(10000, 1000000, size=104),
    'wma30': np.random.rand(104) * 100,
}

fyh_value = np.random.rand() * 100
data['fyh'] = [fyh_value] * 104

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

bull_color = 'green'
bear_color = 'red'

bar_width = 0.8
stick_width = 0.1
fig_size = (10, 6)  
line_width = 2
width = [0.8]*104

def plotstock(df: pd.DataFrame, output_plot_dir: str):
    df = df.reset_index()
    up = df[df.close >= df.open]
    down = df[df.close < df.open]

    plt.figure(figsize=fig_size, dpi=80)
    plt.style.use('default')
    figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, height_ratios=[3,1])
    axis[0].margins(x=0.0, y=0.1)
    axis[1].margins(x=0.0, y=0.1)

    axis[0].bar(up.index, up.close-up.open, bar_width, bottom=up.open, color=bull_color) 
    axis[0].bar(up.index, up.high-up.close, stick_width, bottom=up.close, color=bull_color) 
    axis[0].bar(up.index, up.low-up.open, stick_width, bottom=up.open, color=bull_color)

    axis[0].bar(down.index, down.close-down.open, bar_width, bottom=down.open, color=bear_color) 
    axis[0].bar(down.index, down.high-down.open, stick_width, bottom=down.open, color=bear_color) 
    axis[0].bar(down.index, down.low-down.close, stick_width, bottom=down.close, color=bear_color)

    axis[0].plot(df.wma30, color='blue', linewidth=line_width) 
    axis[0].axhline(df.iloc[-1].fyh, color='orange', linewidth=line_width)  

    axis[0].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axis[0].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    index_gaps = np.diff(df.index)
    bar_widths = index_gaps * 0.8  
    bar_widths = np.insert(bar_widths, 0, 0) '
    '
    axis[1].bar(df.index, df["volume"].values, width=bar_widths)
    
    axis[1].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axis[1].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plotstock(df, "")
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]